# Parse JSON in Drools WHEN block

Tags: drools, rule-engine

I am trying to automate the rule creation using Rule Template.
I am using ResultSetGenerator which will get the result set from Database and create the rule.

One of the column(Grade) in the DB table is of type JSON with following value:

```
{
 "grade":"A",
 "subjects":["Math","Geography"]
}
```

I want the use the above JSON in drools WHEN block in the following way.

```
rule "TEST"
WHEN
  s:String(this==@{Grade})
THEN
  //DO SOMETHING
```

How can I parse the Json of the Grade column to get the value for "grade" attribute from it and use it in WHEN block.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning the JSON to a Map object instead.
The "subjects" element of the Map object should be able to be assigned to a List object as well.

We have a rulesengine that passes raw JSON as facts, and we parse through the JSON by using Map() in the WHEN section.